# Rewrite permalinks for custom posttype and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

How to rewrite permalinks for a custom posttype and custom taxonomy?

I have a custom taxonomy: region, and a custom posttype: business.

Now, how to rewrite the permalink, so that

- for a category, the fixed "category" part is replaced with the custom taxonomy term:

  `/%region%/%category%/`
- for a business: `/%region%/%category%/%business%/`

I'm stuck with this. However, I did manage to rewrite the permalink for a region to `/%region%/`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'region_init' );
function region_init() {
  // set labels
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Regions' ),
    'popular_items' =>  __( 'Popular Regions' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Regions' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Region' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Region:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Region' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Region' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Region' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Region Name' )
  );
  // create a new taxonomy
  register_taxonomy(
    'region',
    'business',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'label' => __('Region'),
      'sort' => true,
      'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '', 'with_front' => false )
    )
  );
}

add_action('init', 'my_rewrite');
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('typename', 'typename/%year%/%postname%/', true, 1);
    add_rewrite_rule('typename/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?typename=$matches[2]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); // !!!
}
```

Comment: I have a tutorial that should help get you started on more advanced rewrite rules for the post types, http://vocecommunications.com/blog/2010/11/adding-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-types/.  But I haven't yet had a need to try it with a taxonomy included in the permastructure, so there may be some caveats.

Comment: Is the `region` taxonomy hierarchical? Because that would mean WordPress can't know how to split `/limburg/maastricht/food/pizzeria/mamma-mia/` into a region and a category. Businesses will probably require a unique slug, even if they are in separate regions, so you can't have `/rotterdam/pizzeria/mamma-mia/` and `/amsterdam/pizzeria/mamma-mia/`, one of them will need to be `/mamma-mia-2/`. This could be the key to solve this problem: ignore the region and category, do the lookup only on the last part.

Comment: @Jan: the region taxonomy is non-hierarchical. Interesting remark about slug uniqueness. Would it be possible then to rewrite the business name, so that it includes the region. So, e.g. /amsterdam-mamma-mia/

Comment: Indeed, you can define the slug of each post yourself. Does this mean you leave out the region, to get `/pizzeria/amsterdam-mamma-mia/` (which is actually just `/%category%/%postname%/`), or duplicate it, like `/amsterdam/pizzeria/amsterdam-mamma-mia/`? (But... with some regex-fu we can even use `/amsterdam/pizzeria/mamma-mia/` and still have the actual slug be `amsterdam-mamma-mia`.) If you can [come to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) we can try to figure this out together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Custom Post Permalinks (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/) from John P. Bloch did the trick for me. Great /flexible plugin!